# Terraform modules that use a resource group data source can't be evaluated

Tags: azure, terraform

I have written a whole bunch of modules that use a data source to determine the azure location so it's calculated instead of having to provide it. Something like:

**function_app parent module**

```
data "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name = var.resource_group_name
}

resource "azurerm_function_app" "function_app" {
  location                        = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name             = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  ....
```

**resource group parent module**

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = var.name
  location = var.location
  tags = var.tags
}

output "name" {
  description = "The Resource Group name."
  value       = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
}

output "id" {
  description = "The Resource Group id."
  value       = azurerm_resource_group.rg.id
}

output "location" {
  description = "The Resource Group location."
  value       = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
}
```

And when using the modules I now have an issue where the resource group can't be found, because terraform evaluates the data sources before the apply:

**function app child module**

```
module "rg" {
  source   = "../"
  name     = <name>
  location = "Australia East"
  tags     = var.tags
}


module "function_app" {
  source = "../"
  functionapp_name      = "Func-Testing"
  app_service_plan_name = "testappserviceplan"
  resource_group_name   = module.rg.name
  os_type               = "linux"
  ...
```

```
│ Error: Error: Resource Group "<name>" was not found
│
│   with module.function_app.data.azurerm_resource_group.rg,
│   on .terraform\modules\function_app\terraform\azurerm_function_app\data.tf line 1, in data "azurerm_resource_group" "rg":
│    1: data "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
```

I would usually fix the issue with `depends_on = [module.rg]`, but as you may be aware that creates explicit dependency and now I have the issue where the next plan wants to re-create some of the resources. Apparently using "depends_on" has a side effect where the resources can't be calculated, so it has to re-create them to get the values. I am seeing "forces replacement" like this in the next plan:

```
  # module.vnet.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet must be replaced
-/+ resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
      - flow_timeout_in_minutes = 0 -> null
      ~ guid                    = "<id>" -> (known after apply)
      ~ id                      = "/subscriptions/<sub-id>/resourceGroups/<resource-group>/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/<vnet>" -> (known after apply)
      ~ location                = "australiaeast" -> (known after apply) # forces replacement
....
```

So, probably not a good idea to have data sources for resource groups in the modules. Does someone know a way around this in the child modules I can use? Without using "depends_on"? And without me having to re-write a lot of modules :D.

Comment: Your question is not clear. So you are creating `azurerm_resource_group` in a module, and then in a parent module you are using data source to get information about the created resource group?

Comment: Correct. I have also tried using azurerm_resource_group directly, without the module.

The purpose of using the resource group data source in each parent module is to get the location, so we only have to pass the resource group name to each parent module.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your issue is to properly `output` the location or the resource group from module. This means that you would have to add an `output` to your module, e.g.

```
output "rg" {
  value = azurerm_resource_group.rg
}
```

and then in the parent module you reference it as:

```
module "test" {
  source = "./mymodule"
}

resource "azurerm_function_app" "function_app" {
  location                        = module.test.rg.location
  resource_group_name             = module.test.rg.name
```

Alternatively, you have to start using `depends_on`, as you pointed out this is not a good practice in your case.

Comment: Yea that's how I am doing it, but I was outputting the name and location separately. Doing it this way has the same result where it can't find the resource group name. I believe my options are to remove the data source from each module or use depends_on and suffer the consequences. Alternatively I can target the resource group module first and then to the rest later.

Comment: @philthy Not sure what you mean that " that's how I am doing it". Your code in the question shows that you are not doing that at all.

Comment: my apologies. I haven't included the output, but It does reference "resource_group_name   = module.rg.name" which indicates there is an output.

Comment: I have made the question more specific now, hopefully that helps.

Comment: @philthy But you are not using `module.test.rg.location` in the parent module. You are using `data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location` which is the cause of your issues.

Comment: thanks, yes I thought so too. I was hoping there would be another way around me having to remove the resource group data source from each module. What I have done is force terraform to not know the resource group name until apply is ran. Easy fix is to remove the data source from each of my parent modules, or use depends_on in each child module.

Comment: @philthy Yes, you can do this, but using `outputs` would be more natural way of getting the location and name of a resource group from child modules into a parent module.

Comment: Same issue here https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/26074